# Force Application on top of other windows in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-7

I have a Qt application written in C++ that I need to stay on top at all times. I have tried a couple of 3rd party applications already such as:

- [Stay on Top](http://download.cnet.com/Stay-On-Top/3000-2072_4-10430147.html)
- [Always on Top](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13784/keep-a-window-on-top-with-a-handy-autohotkey-script/)

These tools work as expected in Windows XP, however in Windows 7 there seems to be a conflict and my application sometimes falls behind other windws. Does anyone have any suggestions to continually force an application on top via C++, Qt or a 3rd party application?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try set Window Flags?

```
yourWidget->setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

Or something like that.

Example:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-windowflags.html